# Switching RootView within UINavigationController

Tags: ios, objective-c, uinavigationcontroller

I am currently trying to switch the root view controller for a specific UINavigationController. I believe this question has been asked multiple times but nobody has seemed to given a proper answer on stackoverflow.

I am currently using this as a guide: http://starterstep.wordpress.com/2009/03/05/changing-a-uinavigationcontroller%E2%80%99s-root-view-controller/#comments

However, I cannot seem to access the UINavigationController dynamically. When I am in another .m file, it will not be able to access this navigational controller because I have initialized it in my appdelegate.m file.

Any thoughts would be greatly appreciated.
Thanks in advance,
freedom

Comment: Are you trying to change the root view controller of the entire application or of a specific UINavigationController? Your first sentence seems to conflict with the title of the post so I can't tell.

Comment: a specific UINavigationController. I only have one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you initialize the UINavigationController in your app delegate, simply keep a reference to it. Create a property on your app delegate class to store the reference:

```
@interface MyAppDelegate : UIResponder <UIApplicationDelegate> {
    UINavigationController *myRootViewController;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) UINavigationController *myRootViewController;
```

then whenever you want to access it, do something like this:

```
MyAppDelegate appDelegate = (MyAppDelegate *)[UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate;
UINavigationController *rootViewController = appDelegate.myRootViewController;
```

(where MyAppDelegate is the name of your app delegate class.)

Answer (score 0):

How about use a `notification` or a `delegate` , your viewController to send the changing rootViewController message.

And the AppDelegate to receive the message and then change rootViewController.